# Show that a chain is a distributive lattice

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory, lattice-orders

I made this proof, but I don't know if it's correct. Someone correct me if Im wrong.

*Showing a chain $(P,\leqslant)$ is a distributive lattice:*

Assuming $x \leqslant y \leqslant z$ , for $x,y,z \in P$

$(L1)$
We have $x \wedge y =x=y \wedge x.$ Also , $x \vee y =y=y \vee x.$ Easily we see that the comutative property holds for all possible relations between $x,y,c$.

$(L2)$
We have $x \wedge (y \wedge z)=x \wedge y =x = x \wedge z= (x \wedge y)  \wedge z$.
Also, $x \vee (y \vee z)=x \vee z=z=y \vee z=(x \vee y ) \vee z$. So associative property also holds.

$(L3)$ We have $x \wedge ( x \vee y)= x \wedge y=x$, and , $x \vee ( x \wedge y)=x \vee x=x.$

$(L4)$ (idempotent) Also verifies, because $L1$,$L2$,$L3$ verify

Therefore P is a lattice.

To proove its a distributive lattice, I just need to verify that in every possible relation between $x,y,z \in P$ the distributive property holds.

Like $x \wedge(y \vee z)=x \wedge z=x= x \vee x = (x \wedge y) \vee (x \wedge z)$

Comment: The proof of distributivity can be slightly less tedious. Since $(x\wedge y)\vee(x\wedge z)\le x\wedge(y\vee z)$ holds in *every* lattice, we only have to prove that $x\wedge(y\vee z)\le(x\wedge y)\vee(x\wedge z).$ And we can assume without loss of generality that $y\le z.$

Comment: Your proof is good only for x <= y <= z.  Your need to show it is valid for the other ways of ordering x,y,z.

Comment: How are you defining $\wedge$?

Comment: @WilliamElliot $a \wedge b = inf \{a,b \} $, and $a \vee b = sup \{a,b \}$

Comment: You completely ignore the work of many people who try to add some basic information and guidelines as to what tags are used for. Why would this question be of any relevance to integers lattices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To construct a lattice out of a chain (K,<=), first define
. . . x min y = x if x <= y, = y if y <= x,
. . . x max y = y if x <= y, = x if y <= x.

Since K is a chain, these definitions are well defined for all x,y.

To show x min y is the greatest lower bound of A = { x,y },
assume b is a lower bound of A.  Thus b <= x,y and either
x <= x min y or y <= x min y.  Either way b <= x min y.
Thus x min y is the glb of A.

In a similar manner, x max y is the least upper bound of A.
Consequently (K,min,max) is a lattice.

Since a = a min b iff a <= b iff b = a max b
one can, if desired, prove all the equations
for an algebraic description of a lattice.

To show (K,min,max) is a distributive lattice both
. . a min (x max y) = (a min x) max (a min y)
and
. . a max (x min y) = (a max x) min (a max y)
are to be proven.

Before proceeding with the proof, show that if x <= y,
then a min x <= a min y and a max x <= a max y.

For the first equation, there are two cases:  x <= y and y <= x
which by symmetry, only one needs to be considered, that is wlog.

So assume x <= y.  Whence
(a min x) max (a min y) = a min y = a min (x max y).

The second equation is handled in a similar manner.